# How does subtracting pointers p - (p - 1) create integer overflow?

Tags: c, pointers, integer-overflow

Here it is in code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i = 3;
  int *p = &i;
  p - (p - 1);
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler (gcc) warns of integer overflow at the outer subtraction:

```
[user@comp c]$ gcc foo.c
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:6:5: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
   p - (p - 1);
     ^
```

The correct result, 1, is obtained on my machine.

Why?

Is this because pointer addresses are unsigned ints but ptrdiff_t is a signed int and cannot handle those big numbers?

I saw that

```
p - (p);
```

and

```
p - (p + 1);
```

do not cause overflow.

I am trying to understand what is going on behind the scenes here. This is my first question on stackoverflow, please let me know if my question can be improved.

Comment: Note that this code has undefined behaviour. A better example would start with something like `int a[17]; int *p = a + 5;`...

Comment: The core problem is `(p - 1)` since `p-1` is out of bounds.

Comment: What compiler / flags are you using? Even trying to make gcc extra cranky I couldn't get it to complain.

Comment: p-1 is out of bounds because the &i is the first address in memory?

Comment: @LumberingLummox No, no, no, no, no. Once again: pointer arithmetic on `p` is only valid within the bounds of the object pointed to by `p`. Variable `i` may be stored anywhere in memory but `&i - 1` is undefined behavior because it starts from within the object `i` and goes outside it.

Comment: You've shown us an 8-line program and an error message referring to line 12. Please show us the *entire* (short) program you're compiling and the *exact* copy-and-pasted error message, as well as the exact command line you're using.

Comment: @Keith Thompson:  Did I fix the command line quotation? What do you mean by the exact command line? Did you want to know which terminal I am using?

Comment: @LumberingLummox: Yes, `gcc foo.c` is what I was referring to as the command line. That particular message appears only in recent versions of gcc, and the phrasing of the message is incorrect (it's not an integer overflow). I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: And I've submitted a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61240) against gcc. It turns out that gcc issues that incorrect warning even in cases with well defined behavior, so it's a more serious bug than I had assumed.

Comment: This bug shall henceforth be known as the Lumbering Lummox Bug!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic is not integer arithmetic. It's defined in terms of address of array elements. If `p` points to an element of an array, then `p-1` points to the previous element of the same array. If that element doesn't exist, the subtraction has undefined behavior.

For purposes of pointer arithmetic, a single object is treated as a 1-element array. A pointer may point just past the end of an array, but such a pointer may not be dereferenced.

```
int i = 3;
int *p = &i;
```

So far, so good; `p` points to `i`.

```
p - (p - 1);
```

Evaluating `p - 1` has undefined behavior. There is no correct result.

Typically compilers don't generate code to check pointer arithmetic for validity at run time. In a typical implementation, the above will yield the "expected" result of `1`. A compiler might even replace the expression with a literal `1` at compile time -- but in doing the analysis required to make that optimization, it may notice that the behavior is undefined and warn you about it.

As for why you're getting that particular message, that's a question about your compiler, which happens to be gcc. I do not get that message with gcc 4.7.2, but I do get it with both 4.8.0 and 4.9.0. (The command

```
gcc --version
```

tells you which version you're using). gcc is correct to print *some* warning message, but that particular message is incorrect, since no integer arithmetic is being performed. The "integer overflow" message is a bug in gcc that also causes it to print spurious warnings for valid code. I've submitted a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61240), which is currently expected to be fixed in version 4.8.4.

```
p - (p);
```

That's valid (but the parentheses are unnecessary). Subtraction of two pointers yields the distance, in elements, between the array elements they point to. If they don't point into the same array, or just past the end of it, the behavior is undefined. `p - p`, given that `p` is a valid pointer, is simply `0` (of type `ptrdiff_t`).

```
p - (p + 1);
```

Also valid.  `p + 1` points past the end of `i`, which is permitted. The subtraction yields `-1`, again of type `ptrdiff_t`.

Recommended reading: Sections 4 (Pointers) and 6 (Arrays and Pointers) of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: @user2485710 1) This is not a C++ question 2) If you have read somewhere that in C++, `p - 1`with `p` pointer produces an `int`, you should pick your sources with more care. Or, in this particular case, read them more attentively.

Comment: @Keith Thompson Thank you, that helps a lot.  Also very grateful for the comp.lang.c reference.  I am curious how far past the end of  i   one could point?

Comment: @LumberingLummox: A pointer may point *immediately* past the end of an array (in this case, `i` is treated as a 1-element array). Such a pointer is valid, but may not be dereferenced.

Comment: @KeithThompson I just deleted that since they are not useful, thanks.

Comment: @PascalCuoq This question could also be posed for C++, and Keith's answer would still be correct

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Pascal's comment was in response to an earlier (and incorrect) comment that has since been deleted.